# How to fit points to piecewise linear model where all slopes must have the same absolute value?

Tags: r, nonparametric, linear, curve-fitting

The current methodology for the genomic data I have involves fitting a spline to multiple points. However, the underlying biology does not support that the fit should be curved at any points. In fact, the connections between the points should be linear, and the slopes must be the same absolute slope when rising or falling.

I would like to fit a piecewise linear function in R to the data, in order to get a better estimate of the y-value at the maxima and minima. Additionally, I would like to make the assumption that the replication occurs at the same speed, and thus the slopes absolutely must be constrained to the same absolute value.

Below is a graph of the points plotted (chromosome location, coverage).

I have not been able to find any current methodology that uses this particular model type, and I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where the changepoints are, or do you have to estimate them too?

Comment: I'd like to be able to estimate those as well.